# Rails 4 - Why does using includes() not make a join between Pins and Replies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a Rails and Ruby newcomer. I want to optimise SQL queries where I can and I was reading about using includes() to make Rails aware, that I want to eager load and join two tables.

**In my show action on the pin controller:**

```
def show

    @pin = Pin.includes(:replies, :user).where(id: params[:id]).first

end
```

**If I check the log on the queries, I see the following:**

```
Started GET "/pin/1703704382" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-12 15:30:18 +0100
Processing by PinsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1703704382"}
  Pin Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `pins`.* FROM `pins` WHERE `pins`.`id` = 145 ORDER BY `pins`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Reply Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `replies`.* FROM `replies` WHERE `replies`.`pin_id` IN (145)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (22)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 22 LIMIT 1
  Profile Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 22 ORDER BY `profiles`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 22 ORDER BY `profiles`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 22]]
  Type Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `types`.* FROM `types` WHERE `types`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `types`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Skill Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 3 ORDER BY `skills`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Instrument Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `instruments`.* FROM `instruments` WHERE `instruments`.`id` = 6 ORDER BY `instruments`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Genre Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` INNER JOIN `genre_pins` ON `genres`.`id` = `genre_pins`.`genre_id` WHERE `genre_pins`.`pin_id` = 145
  Bookmark Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `bookmarks`.* FROM `bookmarks` WHERE `bookmarks`.`pin_id` = 145
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 22 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `bookmarks` WHERE `bookmarks`.`pin_id` = 145
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `replies` WHERE `replies`.`pin_id` = 145
  Rendered partials/_pin.html.erb (14.3ms)
  Pin Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `pins`.* FROM `pins` WHERE `pins`.`id` = 145 ORDER BY `pins`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 22 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 22]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 22 ORDER BY `profiles`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 22]]
  Rendered replies/_reply.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered replies/_form.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered pins/show.html.erb within layouts/application (21.7ms)
  Rendered partials/_meta.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered partials/_top.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered partials/_tags.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered partials/_search.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 33ms (Views: 27.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

It seems like it is running separate queries to get pins, replies and the user. How can I join these into one query? Surely this could be better optimised.

Thanks for your advice and patience!

Comment: just a note. Why do you use .where(id:params[:id]).first when you could use .find(params[:id]) ?

Comment: I found it wasn't working for me at the time when I tried to then do @pin.title in the view, for example.

Comment: Check `Pin.eager_load(:replies, :user)` vs `Pin.preload(:replies, :user)`. It's better to be explicit than rely on `includes`. Which one is better depends on your goals.

Answer (score 4):

> It seems like it is running separate queries to get pins, replies and the user. How can I join these into one query? Surely this could be better optimised.

This is not automatically true. Hydration (the fact of creating nested records, etc, since you don't get in a hierarchical structure from your DB) can be very costly with many relations. It's actually often times better for your performance to use only a very simple query to fetch every record of one table.

If you still want to join (with shallow relations, it's probably better), you can use [`.joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins)